# Oracle apex apex_application.g_f0x don't get table items

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have a report with apex_item(s). The report is complicated so I show only what is relevant for simplification.
The report is created with:

```
select ID || apex_item.hidden(11,ID) as "ID", 
       apex_item.text(p_idx => 12, p_value => VOLUME) as "Volume" 
from TEMP;
```

That gives:

[image]

On submit page, I have a process that counts the report rows (later I loop on this rows to do some action):

```
apex_debug.warn('count f11: ' || apex_application.g_f11.count);
```

The result is **2** as expected.

The problem - when I try to save changes from the report without submitting the page:

I have a button "update server" which have a dynamic action on click with PL/SQL action:

[image]

The PL/SQL contains exactly the same code as the loop above but the result is now **0.**

My goal is to make actions based on the rows. without submitting the page, But I can't understand how can I loop this rows without submit.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you're running a Dynamic Action of the type Execute PL/SQL Code (now called "Execute Server-side Code"), you can specify page items to be submitted with the action that will be set in session state before the PL/SQL block runs, but I don't think you can specify those `fxx` whatever they're called type of items. I think you have two options:

1. Create a hidden item and populate that with a Javascript action that runs before your PL/SQL action, then submit that hidden item along with your PL/SQL action.
2. Change your PL/SQL code to an Ajax Callback *process*, then invoke it with `apex.server.process` in a Javascript DA. You can specify `fxx` type items to submit with that call.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the solution

Comment: #1 is very straightforward to do